# Validar estado de usuario en Laravel

Tags: laravel

Buenas tardes a todos.

Estoy comenzando a trabajar con Laravel 5.8 y he creado una gestión de usuarios utilizando la autenticación que monta por defecto Laravel.

He incluído un nuevo campo denominado state en la base de dato para desactivar usuarios y evitar así tener que eliminarlos.

Se que este tema se ha visto ya pero estoy un poco verde aún en el entramado y estructura que utiliza Laravel de archivos.

Lo que pretendo es poder comprobar si un usuario tiene el campo state activo (1) además de su nombre de usuario y clave antes de dar acceso al panel de control.

Alguién me puede orientar que clase o clases debo modificar y como?

Gracias por todo.

Comment: tendrias que crear un `middleware` puedes llamarlo `usactivo` en donde defines `if(\Auth::User()->estado){ //codigo para continuar } else {//usuario Inactivo}`

Comment: Hola Manrique, gracias por tu ayuda. Una vez tenga creado el middleware, cómo lo enlazaria con el formulario de login?. Un saludo

Comment: Por ahí te conviene utilizar [soft delete](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#soft-deleting). Eso agrega una columna llamada `deleted_at` que cumple la misma función que querés implementar. Si esa columna tiene una fecha, ese usario está "borrado". Automáticamente Eloquent lo ignora de sus consultas, *entiendo* que para el logueo también.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dejo la solución aplicada a mi pregunta para aquellos que lo necesiten.

En el controlador LoginController he importado el Facade Auth e implementado la siguiente función:

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
   $request['state'] = 1;
   return $request->only($this->username(), 'password', 'state');
}
```

Comment: No olvides cuando te sea posible marcarla como aceptada, de modo que el resto de la comunidad identifiquemos esto como la solución a tu problema

Answer (score 0):

laravel 8. solo tube que importar :

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

y por su puesto agregar el state en la base de datos.

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)

    {
       $request['state'] = 1;
       return $request->only($this->username(), 'password', 'state');
    }
```

Lo use tal como lo compatio el compañero .

Comment: No añadas “gracias” como respuesta. Cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), podrás [votar a favor de preguntas y respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) que encuentres útiles. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/370079)